# How to deal with the wrong benchmark question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Recently, I saw some questions caused by OP's wrong benchmark, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25073124/why-static-member-variable-are-slower-than-local-variable) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25029785/speed-of-if-compared-to-conditional). Personally, I have also asked those questions and I can understand them. But it's **not so good for SO** because those question themselves are **wrong**. And to remind them of [how to write a benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java/513259#513259) every time is boring.

So my question is:

- Are those good questions? How to deal with?